# How to display this specific schema with flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: schema]

code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">box</div>
        <div class="test1a">
            <div class="text1a">text1a</div>
            <div class="text2a">text2a</div>
            <div class="text3a">text3a</div>
            <div class="text4a">text4a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="test1b">
            <div class="text1b">text1b</div>
            <div class="text2b">text2b</div>
            <div class="text3b">text3b</div>
            <div class="text4b">text4b</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  padding:10px;
  background:white;
}

.container {
  padding:10px;
  backgorund:black;
}

.box { 
  background:red;
}

.test1a { 
  background:green;
}

.text1a {
  background:blue;
}

.text2a {
  background:red;
}

.text3a {
  background:yellow;
}

.text4a {
  background:orange;
}

.test1b { 
  background:blue;
 }

.text1b { 
  background:green;
}

.text2b { 
  background:red;
}

.text3b {
  background:yellow;
}

.text4b { 
  background:orange;
}
```

- fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/2v79vmz4/1/

So I would like to achieve this with flexbox. And the important thing is that text1a should have same width as text1b and so on - text2a with text2b etc. (the length of text is different every time).

When shrinking (window) they should change from row to column.

"box" text and all other texts should be center in their squares. Squares should stretch for all available places.

Answer (score 2):

I added the class `textbox` to all textboxes, made the textbox containers (`.test1a` and `.test1b`) flexboxes, allowed the childs (with the class `textbox`) to wrap in the box (`flex-wrap: wrap`), made the textboxes equal width with `flex: 1` and that is basically it. Just change the flex-direction to column at a specific breakpoint and your layout is mobile-ready.

https://jsfiddle.net/2v79vmz4/2/

I'd suggest to learn [the basics of flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) over at css-tricks for example.

Comment: Thank you - https://jsfiddle.net/2v79vmz4/3/ this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Well done @Paul. Just a heads up: there's a typo in the .container: `backgorund:black;`